# Change an input value in a cell to another value depending on what the input was

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What I would like to do is change a number input in the rating column (G3:G9001) to the corresponding number of stars (from 1-10).

[image: The sheet]

However I could not figure out how to do this. As a test I tried to change any input to 'asdasdasd aka test' but the way I tried did not work:

[image: The code]

Answer (score 1):

This is more a workaround than a real solution, but add this to the scripteditor and change to sheet name..

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== 'Sheet2' || e.range.columnStart !== 7) return;
e.range.setFormula("=rept(char(9734)," + e.value + ")")
}
```

Since I do not know how to work with a star symbol (char) in GAS, the script writes a formula to the edited cell (in col G) which replaces the number that is typed in with that number of stars.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would really like it do be done automatically though. There are going to be others using this sheet at the same time, therefore I would like every script to function without some form for input by a user that could have an effect on other users (with the exception being editing a cell).

Comment: Just to be clear: In the above, the only input a user would have to do is write a number (e.g. 5) into col G. That typed number will automatically change in 5 stars, thanks to a formula that is placed (automatically).